# Regex for only allowing only decimals less than 1

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex in PHP to only allow only 2 decimal places to the right of the decimal and no digits on the left side of the decimal. What I have so far allows digits to the left side of the decimal point.

```
/^\.[0-9]{1,2}$/
```

Thanks in advance.

Allowed

```
.01
.40
.99
```

Not Allowed

```
1.01
5.50
1.99
```

Comment: `/^\.\d{1,2}$/` (escape the dot)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[.]{1}[0-9]{2}$/
```

That regex matches the character "." 1 time and any number after, exactly two times. If the string is not in the format .01 or .23 and so forth, it wont accept it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want *exactly* two digits after the decimal: `/^\.\d{2}$/`

Assuming you want one or two digits after the decimal: `/^\.\d{1,2}$/`